# unable to set names to a vector or matrix

Tags: r

Probably an easy one, but I still can't get it to work. I have a matrix of values:

```
Browse[2]> x
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13] [,14]
[1,] 48.6 83.1   21  155 63.1 47.4 49.6 59.1 17.5  20.4     0     0     0     0
```

and I have a matrix that contains values which I'd like to consider as names:

```
Browse[2]> a[0,]
 [1] X2.000 X2001  X2002  X2003  X2004  X2005  X2006  X2007  X2008  X2009  X2010  X2011  X2012  X2013 
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

I'm trying to set the names of x but I'm unable to:

```
Browse[2]> colnames (x) <-a[0,]
Browse[2]> x
     numeric(0) character(0) character(0) character(0) character(0) character(0) character(0) character(0) character(0)
[1,]       48.6         83.1           21          155         63.1         47.4         49.6         59.1         17.5
     character(0) character(0) character(0) character(0) character(0)
[1,]         20.4  

      0            0            0
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: May be you need `colnames(x) <- a[1,]` as indexing in R starts from 1.

Comment: a  is a matrix that I loaded from a CSV file. The header is a[0,] which is the first row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In R , the index starts with 1.  Probably, the OP is looking for column names of 'a'.

```
colnames(x) <- colnames(a)
```

Comment: Thanks. But a[1,] has a completely different value i.e. i don't need it. The reason for a[0,] is that it contains the names I picked up. I don't mind copying a[0,] to something else as long as I can use it as the names

Comment: @EranZwilling As I mentioned the indexing starts with 1.  You will not get any output with a[0,]

Comment: @EranZwilling If you meant to have `X2.000 X2001  X2002`, it is the column names of `a`.  Try `colnames(x) <- colnames(a)`

Comment: thanks. 
But then I can add the following code:
y <- vector ()
y<- a[0,]
Browse[2]> y[2]
[1] X2001
so i have a vector y now. Still, how can I use y to be the names for x ?

Comment: Don't use `a[0,]`. Just forget about it. You are looking for `colnames(a)`.

Comment: @EranZwilling  In R, I don't want to repeat what I said.  Indexing starts with 1.

Comment: @akrun Great ! thanks. this is what I was looking at!
Appreciate it :)

Comment: @PierreLafortune Thanks a lot ! :)